# .GetFiles (path).length seems to think there are multiple files when there is only one

Tags: vb.net, directory, getfiles

I'm trying to have my application recognize a file that I have in my local drive but it seems to think that there are multiple files in there when there is only one....

This is what I'm doing ....

```
Dim filePath As String = "c:\Importantfile\FileToCheck"
Dim FileNo As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(filePath).Length
```

I mean it seems like this is the correct synthax since it actually recognizes that there are files but is there a reason why it would think there is multiple files - I made sure there is only 1 file....

Comment: You know that your `FileToCheck` is a directory and `GetFiles` returns all files in that directory?

Comment: @TimSchmelter FileToCheck is a folder and within that folder I have 1 file. So is it wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no hidden files there?

Comment: @steve not that i see - i only see one file that is it. I recently deleted another file out of there. Do you think i need to reboot or soething.

Comment: Can only suggest to check with https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files No there is no need to reboot to adjust for the deleted  file

Comment: @steve it's already checked in as is shown in the article. (to show hidden)

Comment: What value are you getting?  You expect `1` but what do you get?

Comment: @plutonix - 2 , there is another folden in \ImportantFiles called FileToCheckDuplicate - I don't know if that could have anything to do with it. I definitely specify the path and when i check it in immediate window it's showing the path correctly except for the count

Comment: Pretty easy to discover more info: `Dim theFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filePath)` and examine the contents

Comment: it's giving me an error (nothing specific just underline) without .length @plutonix

Comment: I have no idea what "a debug without length" is.  It should give you the array of files, there apparently are 2, so looking at the contents should give you the name of the mysterious other file.

Comment: @plutonix - when I don't have .length with that statement - it underlines directory.getfiles(filePath) and does not let me debug

Comment: It is perfectly good syntax unless you already have a `thefiles` variable or something (or `As Integer`).  Hold your mouse over the underline and it will tell you the problem.  In general, sounds like there are some details missing

Comment: @plutonix - it's showing me 2 same files - one of them has this added before it ~$

Comment: Sounds like a temp file of some sort.  I am not sure what the issue is:  You check for how many files, it says 2 and there are 2.

Comment: @plutonix well theres only one visible file and another file wirh that same name for no reason i know of and its preventing me from doing something

Comment: What type of file is it?  What are the attributes of the file with the ~$?  If you do `Dim fi As New FileInfo(path to ~$ file)` and then examine the properties of `fi` what are the Attributes?  That seems like a temporary file, perhaps from MS Office?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway yes it's a word file. Looks to be all set I recreated the directory and it shows only as one. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your filename (or part of it) or extension you can try using

```
Dim Path As String = "c:\Importantfile\FileToCheck"
Dim Pattern As String = "*.pdf" 'This gives you all pdf files
'or
Dim Pattern As String = "MyFileStartName*" 
'This gives you all files having name starting with"MyFileStartName"
Dim FileNum As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(Path, Pattern).Count
```

Comment: i have a file and another file (same file) with ~$ before it. So i dont know what this means

Comment: It could be a temporary file. Just use patten to select the right name